# Python SocketServer error upon connection

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, socketserver

I am running a Python server using the `socketserver` module in Python 3.1. Every time I get a connection from the client (which succeeds client side), my server receives an error. Here is my code:

```
import socket
import socketserver
import string
import struct

class Server(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.address = self.client_address[0]
        print("%s connected." % str(self.address[1]))
    def handle(self):
        message = self.request.recv(1024).decode().strip()
        print("%s sent: '%s'" % (self.address,message))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = socketserver.TCPServer(("localhost",22085), Server)
    print("Socket created. . .")
    print("Awaiting connections. . .")
    server.serve_forever()
```

And here is my error:

```
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 49669)
----------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python31\lib\socketserver.py", line 281, in _handle_request_noblock
    self.process_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\socketserver.py", line 307, in process_request
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "C:\Python31\lib\socketserver.py", line 320, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 positional argument (4 given)
```

The odd thing I noticed about the error is that the port it gives on the second line is different than the port I'm using. I'm not really sure what the error is here...

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try calling the `__init__` method of the superclass:

```
class Server(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.address = self.client_address[0]
        print("%s connected." % str(self.address[1]))
        super(Server,self).__init__()                  # Init your base class
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam ! I did't realize I was overwriting the __init__ method. I'll accept your comment as the best once stackoverflow allows me. However, I'm still receiving the error because it takes more than one argument... is there any way to call my code when the object is created without overwriting the existing constructor?

Comment: try removing `decode()`, leaving it as `self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()`. See here: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/socketserver.html#module-socketserver

Answer (score 1):

Almost a decade later, I had the same problem. (Python 3.9)

Thanks to the voted answer above as guidance, I was able to find out that the Customised RequestHandler is expected to take 3 arguments, so I had to override a 3-parameter `__init__` as follows to resolve the errors.

```
class ServerRequestHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_addr, server):
                # Custom initialisation code here....
                super().__init__(request, client_addr, server)
```